# Event Hub - REST API got error_code 40403, "message": "Consumer instance not found."

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

I installed a Bluemix Message Hub Service, then add Message Connector to get streaming from Twitter. After that, I got a REST API url to consume the data stream. I posted the REST url using firefox RESTClient with associated header and credential, but got the 40403 returned error code.
Thanks for your advising.

Comment: Any additional info you can provide about your code would be helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

As Hugo has pointed out, consumer instances are deleted after 15 minutes of inactivity. Since consumer instances are not persisted, they may also be removed if the REST service is restarted. To ensure that a REST application can cope with these scenarios, the application should recreate the consumer instance on receiving 40403 error code. Persistent metadata for consumers is retained for consumer groups rather than instances, hence your newly recreated consumer instance should be able to continue processing messages from where the old one left off.

Answer (score 2):

A possible scenario for error "Consumer instance not found" is because REST proxy consumer is deleted after 15 minutes of no polling activity. I'm not sure if this apply to your case. If not, can you please provide more detail if this is the first time you wanted to consume and this error occurs or was you be able to consume before.